# Error when using step_dummy() to handle categorical variables with tidymodels, recipe, bayesian

Tags: r, bayesian, tidymodels, r-recipes

I am trying to use the bayesian package to build a tidy bayesian model. I am mostly following the [bayesian's get started vignette](https://hsbadr.github.io/bayesian/articles/GetStarted.html), although my specific use-case differs slightly in that I am trying to model a numerical variable as a function of a categorical variable. Based on the vignette, I would expect the following code to work.

```
#Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(recipes)
library(bayesian)
library(workflows)

#Create recipe
rec_obj <- recipe(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris %>%
                      select(-Sepal.Width, -Petal.Length, -Petal.Width)) %>%
  #Variable transformation
  step_dummy(Species) %>%
  step_log(Sepal.Length, base = 10)

#Create model
model_obj <- bayesian(
  family = gaussian(),
) |>
  set_engine("brms") |>
  set_mode("regression")

#Create workflow
workflow_obj <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(rec_obj) %>%
  add_model(
    spec = model_obj,
    formula = Sepal.Length ~ Species
  )

#Fit model 
#(this step does not run)
model_fit <- workflow_obj %>%
  fit(data = iris)
```

I am able to create the objects for the recipe, model, and workflow. However, when I try to fit the model, I get the following error:

```
Error: The following variables can neither be found in 'data' nor in 'data2':
'Species'
```

Answer (score 2):

In your workflow change the formula to `formula = Sepal.Length ~ .`.

After `step_dummy` you've transformed the data so that the column Species is replaced by dummy columns with different names.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that. It resolved the error message, but it also crashed R.

Comment: @leorar That must be something separate, since it ran the model fine on my machine.

Comment: @leorar Crashing an entire R session is generally never an acceptable error, so if it's narrowly reproducible developers will want to know about it. More often it's the result of putting more memory pressure on your machine that you maybe think you are.